# Prevent a user from terminating a java program?

Tags: java, windows, jar, installation, startup

I want to install a monitoring system on a computer (the program is a jar file) and run it on start up every time any user logs on. However, I don't want the user to be able to terminate it since then it won't be able to be monitored any longer.

We have tried several ways:

- Installing it as a service - the problem here is that our program doesn't work any longer; it can't connect to the computer that's monitoring it. We used "Yet Another Java Service Wrapper" for this, and looked into some other wrappers as well that could help us install it as a service.
- Running the program on start up (using the folder startup), but not giving the basic user the privileges to edit/delete/mess around with the files. However, this seems to slow the whole computer down? This doesn't happen when we run the bat file executing the jar directly. Another issue with this is that the user can just go to the task manager and kill the java process.
- We tried a variation of the previous one to solve the issue of the process being killed, by having another process. One will spawn the other and these 2 processes will keep tabs on each other. If one terminates, the other detects it and runs it to start it up again. Although it can have issues if the user is fast enough in killing both processes before either is respawned again, the bigger issue is that it sometimes has problems with connecting to other computers. We didn't have this problem when it was just 1 jar.

Does anyone have any idea on how these problems can be solved?

The context here is windows, but if you have suggestions for linux and mac that would be nice too!

Comment: You should find out why your code won't work as a service. That's the standard Windows way to make sure your app stays running.

Comment: It seemed as though it had problems connecting to the other computers through the network. The port was open, but it wasn't receiving anything. Are programs running as services restricted in what they are able to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way to go is to run the program as a service. You should investigate any trouble between your application and your system's firewall. If you have windows firewall activated, you should add an exception for java.exe or javaw.exe.

In order to give elevated privileges to your program, you can set the service to run as another user. You can do this from the "Log on" tab in the service properties.

[image: Service properties]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot and the information on where to find the settings! I managed to solve it now... Running it as an elevated user didn't work. What got it to work was that I had to tick the "Allow service to interact with desktop" option when using the local system account. That solved it.

Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: Tanuki Software created a decent program that handles this.http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have the program started under a user with elevated permissions.  On WIndows this would the the Administrator, linux would use root.  On Windows, its likely that you will need to start it as a service. But I really don't know why that would hinder the network communications.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I managed to solve it now... Turns out it wasn't the network communications problem, but the information received could not be displayed so I thought it was a network problem. You were right about the permissions - I tried running it as a windows service again. What got it to work was that I had to tick the "Allow service to interact with desktop" option. That solved it.